# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, datastore

I created Viewmodel instance and it worked few times, now it is showing error while initializing userPermissionViewModel in MainActivity.

I am using DataStore to save data and try to observer the same.

I even tried initializing as below, but no luck

```
userPermissionsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.application)).get(UserPermissionsViewModel::class.java)
```

Error Log

```
2020-12-11 16:13:40.785 13161-13161/com.lobostaffing.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lobostaffing.app, PID: 13161
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lobostaffing.app/com.lobostaffing.app.mvvm.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.lobostaffing.app.mvvm.viewmodels.UserPermissionsViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.lobostaffing.app.mvvm.viewmodels.UserPermissionsViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at com.lobostaffing.app.mvvm.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:231)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.lobostaffing.app.mvvm.viewmodels.UserPermissionsViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at com.lobostaffing.app.mvvm.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:231) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
userPermissionsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserPermissionsViewModel::class.java)
    userPermissionsViewModel.readFromDataStore.observe(this, { userDetailModel ->
        setupNavDrawer(userDetailModel)
    })
```

UserPermissionsViewModel.kt

```
class UserPermissionsViewModel(application: Application): ViewModel() {

private val userPermissionsRepo = UserPermissionsRepo(application)

val readFromDataStore = userPermissionsRepo.userDetailModel.asLiveData()

fun saveToDataStore(userDetailModel: UserDetailModel) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    userPermissionsRepo.saveUserPermissions(userDetailModel)
}}
```

Build.gradle

```
def archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
//Lifecycle components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var userPermissionsViewModel: UserPermissionsViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        userPermissionsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserPermissionsViewModel::class.java)

    }
}
```

And your viewModel:

```
class UserPermissionsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val userPermissionsRepo = UserPermissionsRepo(application)

}
```

Comment: Actually i had this code which started giving me error today(was working perfectly yesterday). Now i uninstalled app restarted Android studio and installed app again and it is working fine.

Comment: Next time don't uninstall it, just click on File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart ... ,  Thanks for accepting <3

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your viewmodel like this

```
yourViewModelInstance = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModelClass.class);
```

Comment: I am initialising the ViewModel in Activity hence instead of "requireActivity()" i have used "this". And still it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

When you need an application context in the ViewModel it should extend `AndroidViewModel`.
ViewModel with context:

```
class UserPermissionsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

or without context

```
class UserPermissionsViewModel : ViewModel()
```

When a regular ViewModel has any constructor paramaters, the default ViewModelFactory does not know how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the right dependencies

```
//lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
```

Comment: I have these dependencies added in gradle file. See edited question with build.gradle code.

Comment: are intialzing your view model like this? 

userPermissionsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserPermissionsViewModel::class.java)

Comment: Yes. tried both the ways, using only "this" and with "ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.application)".

Comment: okay You have to use AndroidViewModel(application) Not ViewModel()

Comment: because you are passing application

Comment: and don't need to use factory if you are just passing application

Comment: I used AndroidViewModel(application) too and it was giving same error so i changed to ViewModel(). but error still exist.

Comment: I will answer a new answer to show you how I fix it